# f:validateRegex pattern for > 0.0

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, primefaces, xhtml

Before we start I want to inform you that I have done a lot of searching and have looked at all of the "**Questions that may already have your answer**", all over Google, and the `<f:validateRegex pattern="" />` forms and the can not come across; how, by using `<f:validateRegex pattern="" />` to make sure the entered value is greater than 0.0.

I am making a BMI calculator using **PrimeFaces** and I need this validation.

Here is the code where I am asking for the input:

```
<p:inputText id="height" 
    value="#{peopleData.height}" 
    size="6" 
    required="true">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9+]+.+[0-9]+"/>
</p:inputText>
```

I was going to set `pattern="[0-9+]+.+[1-9]+"` but then the user would always need to have could not have a *height* of anything like `*.0`

I am absolutely lost with this and any suggestions would be awesome! Even if the solution would involve using something other than `<f:validateRegex/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex'es are mostly usefull for String validtion. As you request a Float/Double as input, try:

```
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.1" maximum="..." />
```

This tag only allows digits and numeric values within the min-max-range.

See also: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_validatedoublerange_tag.htm